# App Store guidelines 2.6 Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, appstore-approval

I was wondering if the following guideline:

> 2.6 "Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected"

means that you cannot read data retrieved from a `NSUrlConnection`. In my app I download the page source from my website and parse it into usable data. That won't disobey the guideline, will it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is a customer support request. See: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not what it means at all. You're fine. Guideline 2.6 is intended to refer to applications that try to access system files (*i.e*, on the phone) outside the app sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I have published a couple of apps that do exactly what you describe: they get data from a web server, parse it into some data, and cache it locally. So I can confirm from my experience that this is fully supported behavior as per the App Store guidelines.